# set on click on each SVG node

Tags: jquery, asp.net, svg

I have a SVG file loaded in ASP.net page with embeded tag:

```
<embed onload="myFunction()" id="svg_file" src="TEST.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

In myFunction I want set for each node in TEST.svg a method onclick.

My file SVG looks like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="595.28px" height="841.89px" viewBox="0 0 595.28 841.89" enable-background="new 0 0 595.28 841.89" xml:space="preserve">

<g ID=POS1>
  .....
</g>
<g ID=POS2>
  .....
</g>
```

How I can do it in jquery? thanks